# Cron Expression for Job to Run after Specific Number of Months and Days

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, cronexpression, crontrigger

I am working on quartz plugin in grails application. I want to create a Cron expression for job to be scheduled after specified number of days. But number of days can be greater than 30 which means in this situation job will be scheduled after each 'M' number of months and 'D' number of days.

I am unable to create Cron expression for this use case as here I think I need to specify both number of days and number of months. What can be possible Cron expression for this ? How can I schedule a job to execute after specific number of days and days can be any number greater than Zero.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Tell us detail about environment in which you are  trying  to set cron job, like ububtu(linex) or windows ..

Comment: yes I should have included this info as well. I am trying to setup this job in 'Windows'

Comment: Do you want the job to execute x number of days after your application starts?

Comment: yes it will start immediately after user make settings. So when user will make setting, job will be executed after each X number of days.